# pg-promise Chaining Queries for Task and Transactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I have seen pg-promise tasks and tx to reuse same connection we can use

```
db.task(t => {
return t.one('SELECT id FROM Users WHERE name = $1', 'John')
    .then(user => {
        return t.any('SELECT * from Events WHERE userId = $1', user.id);
    });}).then(events => {// success
 }).catch(error => {
// error
});
```

But what if I have two different files and e.g. UsersModel.getUser(username) and EvenModel.getUserEvent(userId). Is there any way I can pass transaction or task objects.

thanks

To further elaborate I have a File LoginController.js

```
function login(){
UsersModel.getUser(username).then((response)=>{
    return EventModel.getEvent(response.ID);
}).then((result)=>{
    res.send(result);
})
```

}

and if we see implementation of getUser it is something like this

```
export function getUser(username){

return db.any('SELECT id FROM Users WHERE name = $1', username);
}
```

So how should I refactor keeping UsersModel and EventModel separate

Comment: In Node.js it doesn't matter how your source files are organized, it does not affect the use for other libraries. So what is your question really about?

Comment: Sorry I may be unclear but basically UsersModelgetUser has the query select id from users.. and EventModel has its own query I have used db.any in both of the functions how to pass the t for task to those models

Comment: For one thing, if you want to pass in the task context, why not just pass in the `t` variable and then use it inside your model? And if you are asking about the best way to organize the data models, then check out [pg-promise-demo](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo).

Comment: I have edited the question Please have a look at it again

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach to building large database application with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) is well laid out in [pg-promise-demo](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo).

But if you want to keep your traditional data models, then in order to make model methods work correctly within tasks and transactions, you should update your methods from this:

```
function getUser(username) {
    return db.oneOrNone('SELECT id FROM Users WHERE name = $1', username);
}
```

to this:

```
function getUser(username, t) {
    t = t || db;
    return t.oneOrNone('SELECT id FROM Users WHERE name = $1', username);
}
```

And then pass it optional task/transaction context when available.

Comment: thanks i have seen pg-demo but it has users and products couldnt see transactions or more complicated scenarios in it. Yes of course but I was unable to get it. thanks for your answer

Comment: @dev123 yeah, I've been thinking about extending it to include such examples. Basically, in that architecture when inside a task/transaction, you automatically get access to all your repository methods, and that's the beauty of it.

Comment: @dev123 does it not answer your question? You didn't accept the answer.

Comment: can you please mention controller logic of passing transactions

Comment: @dev123 I'm not sure how it will fit into your controllers, it is up to you. In the meantime, I have updated [pg-promise-demo here](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo/releases/tag/v.0.6.3), to show the proper use of tasks.